# Synchronizing forked processes with pthread_mutex in C

Tags: pthreads, fork, clone, mutex, semaphore

Is it possible to use mutex from pthread.h to synchronize processes created with fork() from unistd.h? Afaik, both in the end are using system call clone().

I am asking it in the scope of shared memory segment (from ipc.h, shm.h) with critical data, which should be protected against concurrent writes from different processes. In that memory then semaphores can be defined and later used in different processes. Why couldn't mutexes be used instead of semaphores?

Why am I asking?

First of all I was told that it won't work, without receiving any explanation for that. On the Internet I was not able to find any answer so I decided to ask here.

Second, forked process is safer than thread created with pthread_create - if forked process crashes, the rest of the program continues to work and if thread crashes then whole program exits.

Third, mutexes seem to be more human-friendly than semaphores in managing.

Comment: *First of all I was told that it won't work*  Whoever told you that was wrong.  See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.html *if forked process crashes, the rest of the program continues to work*  It's not that simple if your crashed process was holding a mutex lock when it crashed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle
*if your crashed process was holding a mutex lock when it crashed* - yes, right. I didn't consider that scenario.

I know it might sound dumb from my side, but then what does stand on the way of using pthread_mutex in shared memory segment for forked processes?

Comment: You can use robust mutexes.  See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getrobust.html  Note that means you have to check the return value from `pthread_mutex_lock()`, and if the lock fails you have to check if the return value is set to `EOWNERDEAD`.  In that case, the thread that just tried to lock the mutex needs to fix things, and then call [`pthread_mutex_consistent()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_consistent.html).  Note the link in my first comment has an example of a process-shared mutex in it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Awesome! Thank you for this explanation, I understand it now clear.